# When citing in MLA, do you need to cite the same source twice?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I have a Works Cited in MLA style. Two of my sources look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/a/x.html
http://www.example.com/a/y.html#42
```

Do I need to cite both pages, or do I just cite `example.com`?

Comment: Are you citing them as distinct sources (like articles written by different authors/on different topics, analogous to an edited collection) or are you citing the entire example.com as a single source (and the two pages are more analogous to different pages within a monograph)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL in a reference should lead the reader directly to the material you have used and cited.  Unless example.com has *only* those two items, you should cite each one.